# Null reference with recurring paypal payment with initial amount

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to create Recurring Payments Profile. I am able to successfully create subscription. Now I want to create subscription with initial payment. I have added the following code:

```
    CurrencyCodeType currency = (CurrencyCodeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CurrencyCodeType), "USD");
    BasicAmountType intialPaymentAmount = new BasicAmountType(currency, "4000");
    scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails.InitialAmount = intialPaymentAmount;
```

But above piece of code throws null reference object error.

This exactly throws me the error:

```
scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails.InitialAmount = intialPaymentAmount;
```

But in debug mode there is everything in `intialPaymentAmount`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So when you add a breakpoint or otherwise debug: which of those things is `null`? `initialPaymentAmount`? `currency`? `scheduleDetails`? `scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails`?

Comment: nothing, its showing me the currency as well as amount everything

Comment: It seems its not the correct way to initialize the ActivationDetails.InitialAmount, I am trying to find out,in meantime i am also looking for any help from so

Comment: and where does the exception say that the error happened, relative to that code? what is the `.StackTrace` of the exception? if you run it in the debugger: where does the debugger stop to tell you about an exception? We aren't psychic...

Comment: re the edit: can you confirm that `scheduleDetails` is not null, and that `scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails` is not null? Also, again: what is the `.StackTrace` of the exception?

Comment: Oh I am able to get rid of error with {code}  ActivationDetailsType acd = new ActivationDetailsType();
        acd.InitialAmount = intialPaymentAmount;
        acd.FailedInitialAmountAction = FailedPaymentActionType.CANCELONFAILURE;
        scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails = acd;{/code} checking for result

Comment: Ultimately, all NREs come down to a: find the `null`, b: either make it non-`null`, or don't try to access members on it

Answer (score 1):

This way I resolved the issue

```
        BasicAmountType intialPaymentAmount = new BasicAmountType(currency, "4000");
        ActivationDetailsType acd = new ActivationDetailsType();
        acd.InitialAmount = intialPaymentAmount;
        acd.FailedInitialAmountAction = FailedPaymentActionType.CANCELONFAILURE;
        scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails = acd;
```